# Data persist in redis even after prescribed timestamp

Tags: node.js, express, caching, redis, ioredis

I'm building a chatroom cache which should persist for 2 min in redis database, but even after using expireat method cache does not get cleared.

This is my code for storing the cache

```
//check whether room already exists or not
//if not set certain expiry timestamp 

client.lrange(room,0,-1,async(err,replies)=>{
    console.log(err,replies)
    if(replies.length==0)
      {
        const when = 2*60
        client.set(room,[],'EX',when,(err,ans)=>{//here in seconds
               console.log(`setting expiry at ${ new Date(Date.now() + when*1000)}`) //here in milliseconds 
        })
      }
  })

//push the messages into room list at redis 
await client.rpush(room,`${from}:${message}`);
```

But even after desired timestamp is passed messages continue to persist.
I will be more than grateful if somebody guides me.
Thank you in advanced!

Comment: https://github.com/luin/ioredis/issues/1493

Comment: Actually the issue was raised by me only :).